# JDBC Oracle stored procedure ref_cursor using vertx

Tags: java, oracle, vert.x, ojdbc

I am trying to read an Oracle stored procedure returning a ref_cursor using vertx3. The same procedure is working if I edit it to return clob and use JDBCType.CLOB but for some reason I have to use ref_cursor. Can someone please help me?

```
JDBCClient client = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject()
                .put("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8787:TEST")
                .put("driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
                .put("user", "user")
                .put("password", "****"));

 client.getConnection( connection -> {
      if (connection.succeeded()) {
          SQLConnection con = connection.result();

         JsonObject params = new JsonObject()
                    .put("query", "{ call ? :=  package.procedure(?) }")
                    .put("paramsIn", new JsonArray().addNull().add(89))
                    .put("paramsOut", new JsonArray().add(JDBCType.REF_CURSOR));

          con.callWithParams(params.getString("query"), params.getJsonArray("paramsIn"),  params.getJsonArray("paramsOut"), query -> {
               if(query.succeeded()){
                     ResultSet rs = query.result();
                     System.out.println(rs.toJson().toString())
                 }else{
                  System.out.println(req.body() + query.cause().toString());
                 }
                });
             } else {
 System.out.println(connection.cause().toString())                 
             }
            });
```

and I get the error :

> { call ? := package.procedure(?) } java.sql.SQLException: Type de
>   colonne non valide: 2012

Answer (score 0):

As of Vert.x 3.4.1, cursors are not supported. As a workaround, you could create your own `javax.sql.DataSource` and use it with `Vertx.executeBlocking` to invoke a JDBC `java.sql.CallableStatement`.

For the rest of your queries you can still use Vert.x APIs by [creating a JDBCClient instance from your `javax.sql.DataSource`](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_specifying_a_data_source). This will avoid to maintain two different connection pools.

Comment: that exactly what i do in the version 3.2.1 of Vert.x, i ask if the is an other way in version 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR` from `com.oracle:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1` instead of `JDBCType.REF_CURSOR`?